# C# - Convert Switch statement to If-Else

Tags: c#, if-statement, listbox, switch-statement

I'm having a bit of trouble getting going on this particular assignment. Taking a switch statement and converting it to if-else. This program utilizes a list box to select the location and show the corresponding time zone.

```
if (cityListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            //Get the selected item.
            city = cityListBox.SelectedItem.ToString();

            // Determine the time zone.
            switch (city)
            {
                case "Honolulu":
                    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Hawaii-Aleutian";
                    break;
                case "San Francisco":
                    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Pacific";
                    break;
                case "Denver":
                    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Mountain";
                    break;
                case "Minneapolis":
                    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Central";
                    break;
                case "New York":
                    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Eastern";
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No city was selected.
            MessageBox.Show("Select a city.");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is problem with `switch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in most programming languages, a `switch` statement and an `if-else` statement are nearly one in the same (generally speaking; a switch may be quicker on certain compilers for certain languages, and I'm not sure about C#  in particular). `Switch` is more or less syntactic sugar over an `if-else`. At any rate, an if-else statement corresponding to your switch would look something like this:

```cs
if (city == "Honolulu") {
    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Hawaii-Aleutian";
} else if (city == "San Francisco") {
    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Pacific";
} else if (city == "Denver") {
    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Mountain";
}
... etc
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: @trysomethingnew: The reason that `switch` might be faster than `if`/`else` is that the compiler may decide that it's better to compile a `switch` into a table-driven pattern (likely using a `Dictionary`). Like Matt Kae, I don't know if the C# compiler does this, but I'd be surprised if it didn't

Answer (score 3):

With this approach you can get rid of `switch` or `if-else` statements

Create a class to represent timezones

```
public class MyTimezone
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create a list of timezones and bind it to the listbox

```
var timezones = new[]
{
    new MyTimezone { City = "Honolulu", Name = "Hawaii-Aleutian" },
    new MyTimezone { City = "San Francisco", Name = "Pacific" },
    // and so on...
}   

cityListBox.DisplayMember = "City";
cityListBox.ValueMember = "Name"; 
cityListBox.DataSource = timezones;
```

Then in the code where you want to use selected timezones

```
var selected = (MyTimeZone)cityListBox.SelectedItem;
timeZoneLabel.Text = selected.Name;
```

Because `Name` property used as `ValueMember` you can use `SelectedValue` property.

```
// SelectedValue can bu null if nothing selected
timeZoneLabel.Text = cityListBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest turning `switch` into a `Dictionary<string, string>`, i.e. separate *data* (city and its timezone) and *representation* (`Label`, `ListBox` etc.):

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> s_TimeZones = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
  {"Honolulu", "Hawaii-Aleutian"},
  {"San Francisco", "Pacific"},
  //TODO: add all the pairs City - TimeZone here
};
```

then you can use it as follow (two `if`s):

```
if (cityListBox.SelectedIndex >= 0) {
  if (s_TimeZones.TryGetValue(cityListBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), out string tz))
    timeZoneLabel.Text = tz;
  else 
    timeZoneLabel.Text = "Unknown City";
} 
else {
  // No city was selected.
  MessageBox.Show("Select a city.");
  ...
```

Comment: Or `timeZoneLabel.Text = s_TimeZones.GetValueOrDefault(cityListBox.SelectedItem.ToString(), "Unknown City")`